# CrudRepository findAll()

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to java and I'm facing the following problem:
When trying to get all records from my table using CrudRepository, I get the following error:

```
2022-03-11 20:31:53.416 ERROR 13788 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/RecognitionException] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.RecognitionException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:636) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:314) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:774) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy95.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy95.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:791) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:769) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:407) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:84) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy98.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.handmadeapi.services.HouseService.getAllHouses(HouseService.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.handmadeapi.controllers.HousesController.getHouses(HousesController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.58.jar:9.0.58]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

My entity looks like this:

```
@Getter @Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "houses")
public class HouseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface HousesRepository extends CrudRepository<HouseEntity, Long> {
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class HouseService {

    private final HousesRepository housesRepository;

    @Autowired
    public HouseService(HousesRepository housesRepository) {
        this.housesRepository = housesRepository;
    }

    public List<HouseEntity> getAllHouses() {
        return (List<HouseEntity>) housesRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And my controller with request:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/houses")
public class HousesController {

    private final HouseService houseService;

    @Autowired
    public HousesController(HouseService houseService) {
        this.houseService = houseService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity getHouses() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(houseService.getAllHouses());
    }
}
```

I tried to just get an iterator, and then translate it into a `List<>`, tried to register in the `List<HousesEntity> findAll()` repository, tried to do `@Autowired` not in the constructor, but over the field. Did not help. The `save()`, `getById()` methods work, but for example the `count()` method returns the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the application here and it worked fine. You didn't provide your application.properties configurarion for the database, so I figured it could be the problem.

I'll leave the configuration that I used to run.

On **pom.xml** add the h2 database dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And on **application.properties** the database configuration

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

You can access the database console on **http://localhost:8080/h2-console**

In case it doesn't solve the problem, could you provide your database configs like I provided above, or if you have, the github repo for this project so I can try to help you ?

**EDIT**

You have to have docker installed on your machine, once you have it.

Installation can be found [here](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop)

Add a **docker-compose.yml** file to the root of your project

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:

  db:
  image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
  container_name: db
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=compose-postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=compose-postgres
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
```

Change the **postgresql configuration** in order to connect to the database running on the docker container.

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:5432/compose-postgres
spring.datasource.username=compose-postgres
spring.datasource.password=compose-postgres
```

Comment: Hello, here is my application.properties:
`spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testhibernate
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=`
I added the first 3 lines after your comment
I also added a dependency to the pom. I'm testing through Postman, but the error persists.

Comment: It seems like you are using postgres right ? So you won't have to add anything that I posted because they are all configurations related to h2 database. Can you post the project on github, bitbucket or something like this so I can run your exact application ? It would be better for me to help you.

Comment: Yes, of course, here is my project: https://github.com/MJSasha/handmade-api

Comment: Hey, I ran your application on my local machine and it worked fine, but I had to use my postgres credentials, so the only reason that comes to my mind to your problem is something related to your local postgres database. I ran it with docker in order to give a solution to you, so you can run it as I ran in my machine, I'll edit my answer so you can see all the differences in the project in order to run it with docker.

Comment: EDIT, I made the changes here in my answer and opened a pull request with them on your repo, so you can see them more clearly. I hope you can run it, if you have any doubts, just adk them here or on github and I can help you. Link for the changes made on the pull request: https://github.com/MJSasha/handmade-api/pull/1

Comment: @MJSasha The exception is thrown at `HousesController.getHouses(HousesController.java:30)` which doesn't even exist in the repo... Maybe update the repo to your current broken state?

Comment: I don't know why and I don't know how, but it started working with my old database. I rebuilt my project and then I was able to get all the data. Thank you very much for your help!